# Unexpected automatic change in webview.xml

Tags: android-studio

I am creating an Android app with webview, yesterday I closed the project at night and it was working fine but today when I opened the project it showing some encoded text in `activity_webview.xml` and the project is not building.
Below is the encoded text:

```
�PNG


IHDR   `   `   �w8  �IDATx��]   XSWھ* �@d   a�Mك@ �U@E�]��
�UD��Z�⾕nڊuG��j��t���v����Ng����3�3%���wr"�-� ��>�g0�s��=��-�������� fS]=�ZG֤AM�:�  ?�� Q���� D���?;�G�/����L�f+f�&G��ĝ�-���?�s�;|�`�(ρ���?�3�?����;����*��������[��}��P�;�����������}bܼ���-'�6m��1p,S����a��!�����x샻�6ںl�&�&8����P���#6��c��t�8������쁴���ն[���ρ�z|"tLuu��g�x��Xbbа-à�����o
v��A��ʔ&sn��#:��3e׶�?k�~�|��rwMO���=��J��8����9���ԉ���,��>��֭|��[�'a�z5���Mƚ�X/>7c�f�þ�jfk׃���׬v�ڸ���y׬��k�0޸�:���?��}��    �H�rm�0��90����s@8�`�t�}`�3$r���^Ka*L���0�;{nX���!�{�"�����`W�k&.�d1�I�~o������ܥO+���gx&u^
x�ps����F��~�2����ҫ|N�|88���. l%`)L��t0��   ��`���@���[//qiO�DF�/]��7b;x�U���xvf�P(�W����C�j ����P��gJH���YI�;Rgx�|0�Z <��  O >�Q}D��4qi��S ��?�0Q���>���}�����
������x�TA�g�YT���f��L�DNP���Q�RkUl��Z����%�~�>�u^#`7G�sɌ���FS�ĥ_�&-M��Yǝ�M߮>��k�����(p����s�`� �q�`�C�(䚈^�
ISɒJ�������
Щњ���0�"|�X���*��%.5o0M\rZ��=m����=̄�z�Et^W��9����ov�R�L �ȡ4al�F�ARt�<6������w
���B�U�z�$ǟd@A�Djb�
�����Ì8��&,��#ش�B�C��,���   J�q��p-9�Y��>�j�6�?NDX�38�
L��5���-    �@��W9�ȍs���f�����8�E\0�/��(�1Ȏ&�X!'��
```

And yes, I don't totally remember about the contents of this file. Please help.
[Error log from Logcat](https://pastebin.com/xVJWPk0E)

Comment: try  "open with" option after selecting the file and try right clicking on mouse or touchpad and select a particular tool to open this file. Mistakenly you may have open it with wrong tool and has become your default tool to open such type of files.

Comment: I didn't specify any other tool to open it. BTW I tried your suggestion and opened the file with Notepad but It still showing the same encoded text.

Comment: Try this then,  if graphical layout is not showing by opening the xml file, try using OpenWith ->Layout Editor on the xml file which you want to open from project explorer under res folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than discussing on unexpected change, may this solution work for you.
Right click on your `activity_webview.xml` and select `show history` from `Local History`.

[image]

Here you would find the previous versions of your file and I am sure you would find the clean copy of your code here.